# global name logger is not defined thru classes?

Tags: python, logging, undefined, global

I cant get logger as a global name... I tried it inside a normal script, and later trying to debug inside the python cli, but its out of my reach apparently...
(as you will notice, I tried to define logger global everywhere, but also without that, no success)

Inside the python cli-program:

```
import time
import datetime
import subprocess
import re
import glob
import logging
from daemon import runner
from lockfile import LockTimeout
import RPIO
import picamera
import atexit
#From here, it should be global right?
global logger
logger = logging.getLogger("DoorcamLog")
import DoorcamExample
doorcam=DoorcamExample.Doorcam()
```

Error returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "DoorcamExample.py", line 28, in __init__
    logger.info('Doorcam started capturing')
NameError: global name 'logger' is not defined
```

DoorcamExample.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    # This works perfect on a Raspbian system because there's no rootpassword required
    os.execvp("sudo", ["sudo"] + sys.argv)
    print('to far!') #This should NEVER be reached, there is something wrong...
    sys.exit(1)

import time
import datetime
import subprocess
import re
import glob
import logging
from daemon import runner
from lockfile import LockTimeout
import RPIO
import picamera
import atexit




class Doorcam:
    global logger
    def __init__(self):
        logger.info('Doorcam started capturing')
        self.pollLightFile='/var/tmp/picam-pollLight'
        atexit.register(self.stopListening)

    def socket_callback(self, socket, val):
        vals=val.split()
        if len(vals) == 0 or len(vals) > 4:
            number=1
            notify=True
            trigger='Socket'
            triggernotify='Socket (value %s)'%val
        elif len(vals) == 1:
            number=int(vals[0])
            notify=True
            trigger='Socket'
            triggernotify='Socket (value %s)'%val
        elif len(vals) == 2:
            number=int(vals[1])
            notify=True
            trigger=vals[0]
            triggernotify=vals[0]
        elif len(vals) == 3:
            number=int(vals[1])
            trigger=vals[0]
            triggernotify=vals[0]
            notify=self.boolval(vals[2])
        elif len(vals) == 4:
            number=int(vals[2])
            trigger=vals[0]
            triggernotify=vals[0], [1]
            notify=self.boolval(vals[3])

        socket.send('self.upload(self.shot(filename=self.filename, number=number, trigger=trigger), notify=notify,trigger=triggernotify)')
        RPIO.close_tcp_client(socket.fileno())

    def startListening(self,channel,port=8080, threaded=True):
        #RPIO.add_interrupt_callback(channel, self.gpio_callback, pull_up_down=RPIO.PUD_DOWN, debounce_timeout_ms=1000)
        RPIO.add_tcp_callback(port, self.socket_callback)
        RPIO.wait_for_interrupts(threaded=threaded)

    def stopListening(self):
        logger.info('Stop listening')
        RPIO.stop_waiting_for_interrupts()


global logger
```

Comment: "Global" variables are only global within a single module, so your `DoorcamExample.py` doesn't have access to `logger` that you defined in some other module.

Comment: @BrenBarn: you should repost your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Global" variables are only global within a single module, so your DoorcamExample.py doesn't have access to logger that you defined in some other module.

In this case, you don't need a global variable, because the logging module already maintains a truly global (i.e., visible from all modules) registry of loggers.  So if you do `logging.getLogger("DoorcamLog")` in any of your modules, you'll get a reference to the same logger.

Comment: Is "Class" the definition of a module, or the DoorbellExample.py script? (In other words, can a module contain multiple classes, and would they be sharing global names?)

Comment: @ExploWare: A module is (basically) one file of Python code.  So yes, a module can contain many classes.  Not sure what you mean by "sharing global names".  Like I said, names are global within a module, so yes, if you create a global variable in a module then all classes in that module will see it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a program-wide global variable in this case. The logging module tracks all loggers created via calls to `getLogger`, so as long as you use the same name, you'll get the same logging object. So calls to `logging.getLogger("DoorcamLog")` will return the same object in both scripts.

Answer (score 0):

As BrenBarn commented, in Python, "global" only refers to the current module's namespace - hopefully, since you wouldn't want a module to depend on some name being defined in the importing module's namespace.

Also, the "global" keyword is only meaningful in a function - every name defined at the module's top-level is by definition global to the module - and it's only useful if you actually want to rebind that name within the function (so Python knows you're not creating a local variable instead).

wrt/ loggers naming, the simplest and more effective solution is to create a logger for each module and just pass the current module's name (ie the 'magic' variable `__name__`), except for executable scripts (which will be named "**main**").